# Identify Subview in UIView by Location (CGPoint)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm trying to work out the best method for finding the exact subview (if any) at a given `CGPoint` in a `UIView`.

Part of my scene/ViewController is a custom `UIView` subclass (designed in a XIB), which presents a `UIStackView` of subviews (also custom, XIB-designed).

The VC has a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on that custom view, and in my `@IBAction`, I want to identify which specific one of its subviews was tapped, then handle it accordingly:

```
@IBAction func handleTap(recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let tapLocation = recognizer.location(in: recognizer.view)
    if let subviewTapped = customView.subviewAtLocation(tapLocation) {
        handleTapForSubview(subviewTapped)
    }
}
```

However, I don't know how to implement that `subviewAtLocation(CGPoint)` method. I wasn't able to find anything in the standard UIView methods.

Any advice on how it should be done would be welcome.

Alternatively, I considered adding a tap recognizer to each of the subviews instead, then delegating to the parent, then to the VC, but that feels inefficient, and like it's putting too much control logic in the views, rather than the VC.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution would be using the `contains(point:)` method of `CGRect`. The idea is to iterate over the stack view's subviews and check which subviews contains the touched point. Here:

```
@IBAction func handleTap(recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let tapLocation = recognizer.location(in: recognizer.view)
    let filteredSubviews = stackView.subviews.filter { subView -> Bool in
      return subView.frame.contains(tapLocation)
    }

    guard let subviewTapped = filteredSubviews.first else {
      // No subview touched
      return
    }

    // process subviewTapped however you want
}
```

Comment: This worked really well, thanks! Just for extra precision, I added a second check to your filtering, which only includes subViews of that custom class:

`let filteredSubViews = stackView.subviews.filter { subView -> Bool in
    return subView.frame.contains(location) && subView as? CustomViewClass != nil
}`

Answer (score 2):

//use hitTest() method. this gives the view which contain the point

```
let subView = parentView.hitTest(point, with: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This approach looks to make sense for some scenarios, but from what I gather in the Apple Documentation for `hitTest` ([link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest)), it actually pulls the _furthest_ view, rather than what's in the immediate `UIStackView`. Therefore, for this need, the `stackView.subviews.filter` method from @ajeferson may be an easier route to the immediate sub-view.